# Radio buttons redirect to another activity

Tags: android

I have a scenario that we should have a single choice mode `radio button` in `listview`. when I click on the `radiobutton` it should go to enable state. when I click on the whole item then it should redirect to the new `activity`.

Comment: if radio.ischecked, then start intent activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a composite view for this. Due to the way the native radiobutton is built you can't differentiate between click on the circle or click on the item.

You can have a radiobutton without text associated to a textview or whatever view you may need. Then you simply listen to clicks on the textview or the radiobutton.

For the radiobutton you can keep the default behavior and for the textview you have a button-like onClickListener.